# Top border not appearing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been asked to work on a website that's using a jQuery library called Wowbook. On each page of the book I've defined elements to contain content. I was having some issues with alignment at the bottom of each page, which I've fixed, but now I have a new problem.  My client insists on one of the elements having a border around it. The top part of the border looks fine in IE but disappears in Chrome. When I click to turn the page, the border momentarily appears.

URL: [Sample page](http://www.jjbrookings.com/ManagedCollections/Monumental.shtml#features/10)

```css
    .pagesleftcontent{ /* this has to have the border */
     position: relative;
     padding: 10px;
     height: 345px;
     overflow: auto;
     z-index: 1;
     border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .pagesleftcontent2{ /* I use this to shorten the element when the heading above wraps onto two lines */
     height: 323px;
    }

    .pagesleft h1{
     text-align:center; 
    
    }
```

```html
    <div class='pagesleft'>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <div class="pagesleftcontent">
        <p>... yadda yadda yadda ...</p>
        
        
      </div>
      <div class="posterID">
        15542
      </div>
      <div class="signature">
        Le Rappel<br>
        Jules Cheret<br>
        France, 1889<br>
        Size: 73&quot; X 52&quot;
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Border works fine in my chrome: 40.0.2214.115 m

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Works fine for me as well.

Comment: Just updated to 40.0.2214.115 m, problem still exists. I wonder if it's a monitor resolution issue

Comment: I'm all the way back on 33.0.1750.154 m and it's working for me as well.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the feedback, everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Border works perfectly fine on iPad aswell as the latest chrome version. Try deleting your browser cache and see if it helps.